# PHP 7.3 (CPanel) update results in 500 server error

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-500, php-7.3

When I upgrade my server from PHP 7.2 to PHP 7.3 I get a server error 500.

I'm using the same packages as I did with 7.2 (and none have been deprecated). My error logs aren't very helpful as they don't provide any inclination of the problem (or anything else, a problem for another day).

I've never had any issues updating my PHP version so I'm not sure why I'm having issues now.

I use htaccess but I can't think why my htaccess file will work with 7.2 and not 7.3. All I get is a 500 Server Error, no additional information.

Does anyone have any ideas? I would be very grateful!

Comment: If you've solved your issue yourself, you should ([and are encouraged to](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)) post your solution as an answer to your question. You should avoid answering your own question in the question itself.

Comment: *Aside:* If your error logs are not reporting anything, then first thing you need to do is check your PHP.ini file and set the correct error log path in the ini file.

Comment: @Martin I'm restricted to htaccess. however, I have corrected the error log issue. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a boo boo, ignore me. Turns out that when you update to PHP 7.3 when using cPanel the necessary sqli/pdo modules get unchecked. In my sleep deprived state I wasn't paying proper attention. Enabling nd_mysqli and nd_pdo_mysql modules fixed everything.

Answer (score 1):

Does index.php ONLY containing the following and still has a 500?

```
<?php
 phpinfo();
?>
```

If so make sure you've disabled the old php 7.2 and enable 7.3

```
 sudo a2dismod php7.2
 sudo a2enmod php7.3
```

this assumes you use apache

Comment: Solved it (see my edit). Your suggestion to use phpinfo() helped me realise my own (seemingly very obvious) mistake, so if for nothing else, thanks for the prompt.

Comment: Sweet! The important thing is you're up and running

Comment: @JustSomeGuy great that you have found the answer. Could you please close the question as answered.